# Angular 2 project keeps loading

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 2 project that keeps loading. I generated it from fountain generator for yeoman.

HTML

```
<h1>{{ hello }}</h1>
```

Component

```
var ng = require('@angular/core');

module.exports = ng.Component({
  selector: 'fountain-app',
  template: require('./hello.html')
})
.Class({
  constructor: function () {
    this.hello = 'Hello World!';
  }
});
```

Module

```
var ng = require('@angular/core');
var ngPlatformBrowser = require('@angular/platform-browser');
var myRoutes = require('./routes');

var HelloComponent = require('./hello');

module.exports = ng.NgModule({
  imports: [
    ngPlatformBrowser.BrowserModule,
    myRoutes.routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    myRoutes.RootComponent,
    HelloComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [myRoutes.RootComponent]
})
.Class({
  constructor: function () {}
});
```

Router

```
var ng = require('@angular/core');
var ngRouter = require('@angular/router');
var HelloComponent = require('./hello');

var RootComponent =
  ng.Component({
    selector: 'fountain-root',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function () {}
  });

var routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HelloComponent
  }
];

module.exports = {RootComponent: RootComponent, routes: routes, routing: ngRouter.RouterModule.forRoot(routes)};
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FountainJS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://fountainjs.io/assets/imgs/fountain.png" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <fountain-root>Loading...</fountain-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bootstrapping

```
require('core-js/client/shim');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

require('@angular/common');
require('rxjs');

require('./index.scss');

var ngCore = require('@angular/core');
var ngPbd = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic');
var AppModule = require('./app');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  ngCore.enableProdMode();
} else {
  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity; // eslint-disable-line dot-notation
  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}

ngPbd.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I'm using a golang as the backend but don't find it necessary to post the code as it is loading the angular index.html fine. I checked for 404 error and there aren't any.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm prefer Angular CLI for scaffolding an Angular app, and using typescript for development because those thing easy to use and widely support and rich documentation.

Comment: I wonder which language is this. :(